# Replacing stock dnsmasq with optware dnsmasq

Tags: linux, dd-wrt, process, dnsmasq

This question if for DD-WRT installed on e3000 with optware.

I have replaced the stock dnsmasq to get logging, using this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=660694
I installed optware on my 16gb usb and installed dnsmasq.

Runs fine when service started, but have a problem:

- On device reboot, the dnsmasq service does not load up. I have to manually load it using "service dnsmasq start".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answers to my problems. May be useful to someone else:

1. "There are always 2 processes running for each dhcp network. The subprocess is because dnsmasq setuids to nobody to run the external script specified in --dhcp-script. This is expected behavior." src: answers.launchpad.net/nova/+question/181398
2. As one of the processes was nobody; during boot up, user 'nobody' was not initialized. Added these two lines to /opt/etc/init.d/S56dnsmasq:

> grep -q nobody /etc/group || echo "nobody:x:99:" >> /etc/group
>
> grep -q nobody     /etc/passwd || echo "nobody:x:99:99:nobody:/var:/bin/false" >> /etc/passwd

Works like a charm!